# How to run java code and pass output of java code as jmeter variables

Tags: jmeter

To run API two mandatory headers needs to passed with the body. Developers have written a piece of java code by executing we get timestamp and signature this data should be passed as header for API. Please find below snapshot when executed on Eclipse

[image]

Please help how to capture java code output and pass this values as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could run it as a normal Java program using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) and extract the timestamp and the signature from the response with [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

---

However the better would be most probably packaging this "piece of java code" [into a .jar file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) (including all [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) if any) and dropping it into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath). Once done you should be able to call "generateSignature()` function from the [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy). It might be a good idea to return some data structure like [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) from it instead of printing the values into STDOUT.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, do you have any code snippet or any blog i use it